# Wifi keeps dropping every 5-10 second and automatically reconnect in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, atheros

I upgraded ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04 and previously there was no problem at all. But after some time my wifi keeps dropping every 5 to 10 second as a result cause packet loss as slow streaming.
My ethernet works fine. I have
Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01) driver

Can anyone please help me with this problem

Comment: Check the logs with `sudo journalctl  -b 0 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager`

Comment: Log file
https://imgur.com/hH4QZ32